# multithreading in kotlin - running some part of a function concurrently

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have this function i want the part were list 'values' is being created to run in threads or concurrently. I want to make sure that the function waits for values list while equating as many fields as possible at the same time?

I keep on trying different ways but the values list is not equated and the function exits without writing in the file and moves onto the next product. This function is called in a for loop of products . Also if possible to keep the order of the values list.

````
suspend fun processProduct(
numberOfFields: Int,
p: Product,
fields: List<Field>,
data: String?,
filterFormula: String?
): Boolean {
val fileJson = JSONObject(data).getJSONObject("file")
val com = COM(p.sku, p.clientId, p.projectId, true, "", null)
//>>>this part
val values =
MutableList(numberOfFields) { i ->
if (fields[i].sourceCode.isNullOrEmpty()) 
  "" 
else 
  com.REFFIELD(fields[i].sourceCode!!, "")
}
//>>>
println(values)
val processedValues = MutableList(numberOfFields) { i ->
if (fields[i].formula.isNullOrEmpty()) values[i] else {
try {
luaService.execute(
p.sku,
p.clientId,
p.projectId,
true,
values[i],
fields[i].formula!!,
null
)
} catch (e: Exception) {
""
} catch (e: Throwable) {
""
}
}
}
numberOfProcessedProducts.incrementAndGet()

val delimiter = if (fileJson.has("delimiter")) {
fileJson.getString("delimiter")
} else {
","
}

val exportEncoding = if (fileJson.has("exportEncoding")) {
Charset.forName(fileJson.getString("exportEncoding"))
} else {
Charsets.UTF_8
}

FileWriter(outputFile!!, true).use { out ->
val formattedValues = processedValues.map { value ->
val formattedValue = value.encodeToByteArray().toString(exportEncoding)
if (formattedValue.contains(delimiter) || formattedValue.contains("\n") || formattedValue.contains("\r")) {
val escapedValue = formattedValue.replace("\"", "\"\"")
"\"$escapedValue\""
} else {
formattedValue
}
}
out.append(formattedValues.joinToString(delimiter))
out.append(System.lineSeparator())
}
return true
}```
````